# Use of abs() on an array in Modelica

Tags: modelica

I am trying to extend my cell-based model of a heat exchanger (hx) with finding the minimum temperature difference. I therefore defined arrays that hold the temperature for each cell my heat exchanger has. Then, I defined each entry of my array that holds the temperature differences to be the difference of the cell-values with the same index. I then want to search for the minimum of the array to find the minimal temperature difference.

Now, whats special about my hx is that hot and cold medium can switch during operation (Always abiding the second law obviously: One fluid undergoes a change of phases, so with regulating the pressure level I can determine if its the hot or the cold medium). That means that I need to store the absolute value of that difference if I want to search the minimum always with the min() function. The arrays are defined as follows:

```
import Modelica.Units.SI

Real nCells;
SI.Temperature Fluid1Temps[nCells];
SI.Temperature Fluid2Temps[nCells];
SI.Temperature dTCells[nCells];

SI.Temperature dTmin;
```

Now, for some reason this does not work for me. Despite using the abs() function around the difference, all values get stored with their original sign. Here is an example of what I tried:

```
for i in 1:nCells loop

  Fluid1Temps[i] = Fluid1Cells[i].T;
  Fluid2Temps[i] = Fluid2Cells[i].T;
  dTCells[i] = abs(Fluid1Temps[i] - Fluid2Temps[i]);

end for;

dTmin = min(dTCells);
```

I tried to apply the abs() function in multiple ways, for example storing the raw difference in one array and then making all of those values absolute by writing the array in the absolute clause. I did not get to the result I want, which is why I am here now.

I hope someone can help me with that question, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dymola appears to use fabs in this case so it seems unlikely to be an error with abs it self. I would recommend double checking that dTCells[] is of size nCells.
Could you provide an example?  
What Modelica tool are you using and what version?

Comment: I edited the question with the definition of the arrays. I am using Dymola 2023.

Comment: From what I know, `abs()` can be applied to scalars and vectors (and arrays in general). So your application of `abs` should work. The one issue I see in the example is, that `nCells` should be an `Integer` not a `Real`. Also there should be no loop necessary...

Comment: Actually `nCells` should be a `parameter Integer nCells`...